# bootstrap how to make a fixed height responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

How can I make a fixed height element responsive with bootstrap 3? For instance I set the carousal's height at 650px. But I can't make it responsive like the images do. Any idea?

css,

```
#article-carousel .carousel-inner{
    height:650px;
}
```

html,

```
<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">

   <div class="active item">
     <img src="style/image/10403889_707684359268375_7804458077651816095_o.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
   </div>
....
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try changing the height of the img element instead of .carousel-inner?

Comment: the images come with different heights so I want to crop them by using overflow hidden...

Comment: Set the img-responsive class to height:100% to allow the image to go full height.

Comment: Generally you make media queries starting from smallest min-width to largest min-width and set the heights inside.

Comment: I have improved the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25981221/947687 by adding css3 `background-size` way. It works in all modern browsers without javascript.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use css3 **object-fit** for resizing your image http://jsfiddle.net/xcoq9xxg/

```
img {
    height: 650px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover; // here
}
```

It works for Chrome and Opera. Use polyfill library for others: https://github.com/schmidsi/jquery-object-fit or https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit.

---

Another way is to use css3 **background-size** http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/rwdspudv/

```
.image {
    height: 650px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

It works in all modern browsers without javascript, but you need to use `<div>` instead of `<img>`:

```
<div class="image" style="background-image: url('my-image.jpg')"></div>
```

Comment: I have improved the answer by adding css3 `background-size` way.

Answer (score 6):

i had the same problem with the responsive fixed height. I use vh instead of px. In my case it works like a charm

```
img {
    height: 85vh;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover; // here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
.carousel-inner > item { position: relative; overflow:hidden; }
.carousel-inner > item > .img-responsive { position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; }
```

or,
I think thats better to do it with js ( with boostrap we'll use jquery ) :

```
...
function init_carousel(){
    H = +($( window ).height()); // or $('.carousel-inner') as you want ...
    $('.img-responsive').css('height',H+'px');
}
init_carousel();
...
```

In this case, add div with the background image into, and your css must be :

```
.carousel-inner > item { position: relative; overflow:hidden;  }
.carousel-inner > item > .img-responsive-fix { position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; text-align:center; padding:0; margin:0; }
.carousel-inner > item > .img-responsive { witdh:auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below this worked just fine for me

```css
<style>
  /* Make the image fully responsive */
  .carousel-inner img {
      width: 500px;
      height: 350px;
  }
  .carousel
  {
   height: 350px;
    width: 500px
  }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          function Screensize() {
        try {
            var height = ((screen.height * 80) / 100);
            document.getElementById('Mapbox').setAttribute("style", "display:block;height:" + height + "px; overflow:auto;");
        } 
        catch (ex)
        {  alert(ex); }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to restyle carousel-control class with media query
here is just an example code to add

```
 @media (max-width: 800px) {
    .carousel-control{
      height:350px;
    }
 }
```