# Bootstrap 4 carousel responsive issue in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have an issue with Bootstrap 4 carousel in Chrome only.

Here is my code:

```
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="carousel-item active">
     <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/1350x350" alt="First slide">
  </div>
   <div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/1350x350" alt="Second slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/1350x350" alt="Third slide">
</div>
</div>
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
 </a>
 <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a> 
 </div>
```

Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/benjamin_edwards/1gx43oph/

and here is an image of what the issue is:

[image: See here]

As you can see the left pane is Chrome and right is Safari. Only Chrome has the blooming issue - has anyone experienced this before?

Cheers,

Ben.

Comment: Can you describe the issue and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I have been searching the web and there is a solution for this

```
.carousel-item.active,
.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev{
 display:block !important;
}
```

I have updated my fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/benjamin_edwards/1gx43oph/

and I got the answers from here:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21611

from my post here:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21966

Hope this can help others :)

Answer (score 0):

if you prefer a responsive carousel with fixed height you can use a div with background cover instead of the normal image like this :

```
.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

<div class="image" style="background-image: url('my-image.jpg')"></div>
```

i found this solution here : [bootstrap how to make a fixed height responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980576/bootstrap-how-to-make-a-fixed-height-responsive#answer-25981221)