# Bootstrap 4 carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Having an unusual issue with Bootstrap 4's carousel, it was working normally then I must have changed something somewhere, tried deleting it and same issue was occurring. My arrows aren't in the right position [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAiLA.jpg)

```
<body>
<ul class="nav justify-content-center">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="landmarks.html">Landmarks</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="images.html">Image Gallery</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="container" align="center">
    <h1 class="display-5">Gallery</h1>
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="carousel-item active">
  <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="beach.jpg" alt="First slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="lake.jpg" alt="Second slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="martyrsquare.jpg" alt="Third slide">
</div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls"  role="button"  data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

The tiny amount of css I have wouldn't affect any of this but just in case

```
.row{
    padding: 20px;
}

body{
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

Comment: does this occur on every image?

Comment: @DavidLee yes, but only within that carousel

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42187081/5128464) helped me solve a similar problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrows seem to be in the right place.  It seems like your image size is what is causing it too look out of place.

Try adding the following class to your css.

```
.carousel-item img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, but now the images stretch in height in lower window sizes

Comment: I take it you have set a hard coded value on the img heights.  Are you open to having space on the sides of the image?

Comment: haven't hard coded values for img heights, would prefer not to have space on the sides

Comment: can you post another picture of the issue as I am having trouble understanding what is now happening

Comment: Just to clarify that's just by making the chrome window smaller

Comment: Try adding height: auto; to the same css class

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either, not sure what it could be

Comment: I've just tested it in Firefox, and it's working fine, must just be an issue with chrome. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: You are welcome.  If it worked in firefox be sure to disable caching when chrome development tools are open.